# Is it possible to subclass a retrieved class via Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to subclass a retrieved class via Java reflection? I'm trying to change the implementation of a method of an already loaded class. I know there is no way to do it via regular reflection methods. But I was wondering if it is possible by subclassing the retrieved class, such as:

```
final Class cls = classLoader.loadClass(className);
Object newRemoteInstance = new cls() {
    @Override
    public void saySth() {
         System.out.println("changed");
    }
}
```

instead of retrieving the exact same implementation with

```
cls.newInstance();
```

And then copying the fields of the already loaded class into the newly created instance and further using this new instance instead of the already loaded one. The class that is to change is not available, so I do have to use reflection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear in your question to what extend it is a must that you need to use reflection for this. Because you could create your instance via reflection and then simply wrap it into your on proxy or decorator to enhance or change its behavior.

```
class MyFactory {
    MyClass create() {
       return MyDecorator(cls.newInstance());
    }
}
```

Where `MyDecorator` implements the same public interface as `MyClass` of course.

However, if you really need to do this via reflection, I know of a couple of alternatives that might work, depending on what you have mind.

**Using Java Proxies**

If your method in question comes from an interface, you could use a Java [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to alter its behavior.

```
OrderService subject = new DefaultOrderService();
OrderService orderService = (OrderService) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
         this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{OrderService.class},
            (proxy, method, args) -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Before method");
                    return method.invoke(subject, args);
                }
                finally {
                    System.out.println("After method");
                }
            }
        );
System.out.println(orderService.getClass());
orderService.getOrder(10);
```

The output above yields somewhat like this for the class name: `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.class` as the class of your proxy.

**Using Java CGLIB**

However, if you are forced to use regular class, not an interface, then you could use a library like [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) instead.

The proxy consists on inheriting from the original class (ie. DefaultOrderService). This has one advantage; it does not need that the class in question implements an interface in order to be able to create a proxy, which seems to be the case in your question.

```
DefaultOrderService subject = new DefaultOrderService();
Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
enhancer.setSuperclass(DefaultOrderService.class);
enhancer.setCallback((InvocationHandler) (obj, method, args) -> {
   try {
      System.out.println("Before method");
      return method.invoke(subject, args);
   } 
   finally {
      System.out.println("After method");
   }
});

OrderService orderService = (OrderService) enhancer.create();
System.out.println(orderService.getClass());
orderService.getOrder(10);
```

The output above yields somewhat like `DefaultOrderService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9017bdba.class` as the class of your enhanced object.

However, both examples are about defining a new class that will have the same interface as another one, they do not alter the original parent class or interface.

Comment: Your last example is exactly what I need thank you! Unfortunately it does not work on Android (on which my project is based) since CGlib generates java byte code whereas Android runs Dalvik byte code. Do you happen know an alternative for Android that offers equivalent capabilties? EDIT: I actually just found http://bytebuddy.net/ and will have a look into it as the author claimed to support Android in its latest version